# How to create an ElasticSearch Query which should not match any of multiple categories

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm looking for documents inside elasticSearch which do not match one or the other brand, but fullFill a fix requirement. I'm looking for any entries which are not from Toyota, BMW or Audi. But the entry must be a superEntry (exact match)

The following Query is what I'm working on:

```
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "superEntry": true
                }
            },
            "must": {
                "bool": {
                    "must_not": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "brand": "Toyota"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "brand": "BMW"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "brand": "Audi"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected: I find any super-entries from any other brand, but not from those 3. The query above still lists me cars from BMW as an example..

Answer (score 2):

Not tested but something like this will help-

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "superEntry": true
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "brand": [
              "Toyota",
              "BMW",
              "Audi"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: while filtering only for one brand it's working, but with 3 brands like in the example, it still allows to return entries from one of those excluded..

Comment: @ChristofBuechi what is the type of your field `brand`? because when I try on my index with type 'string' it is working as expected. or you can try with `brand.keyword`

Comment: the field brand is a String. Seems like I was able to solve my issue while switching away from term to match.. Based on the documentation term should not be used in case of string:
By default, Elasticsearch changes the values of text fields as part of analysis. This can make finding exact matches for text field values difficult.
**To search text field values, use the match query instead.**

[link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)

Comment: Gr8, best of luck mate